# Reset many to many fields from model

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to reset all upvotes from all my Posts with django-orm, don`t know how to write query for that and apply it to the view. Also, maybe it would be better to make separate upvote model than just a field in the Post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='posts',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    link = models.URLField()
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='upvotes', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to reset all upvotes from all my `Post`s

You can do that, for example with:

```
Post.upvotes.through.objects.all().delete()
```

you can for example do that in a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

this will clear the records in the many-to-many table.

> Also, maybe it would be better to make separate upvote model than just a field in the Post.

A `ManyToManyField` is not really a "field", it is stored as a model. You can define the [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), for example with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='posts',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    link = models.URLField()
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='liked_posts',
        editable=False,
        through='Upvote'
    )

class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        'Post',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Oh yes, i meant create separate class for upvote just like you wrote. By the way it works, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
Quite near the end under "Relation sets can be cleared:"

In your example it would be

```
p.upvotes.clear()
```

As for whether it would be better in its own model, are you ever going to need to have any other attributes on your upvotes? Such as whether they are invalid or something (idk?)
If you think you are, then they should go in their own model

You can still use Django's ManyToMany field and all the magic that comes with it, by setting your intermediate model as the `through` attribute
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: But the `p.upvotes.clear()` will only clear the upvotes of a *specific* `Post` `p`, not *all* `Post`s.

Comment: Dont quite understand how `through` works, but i`ll try both ways. Thanks